# Android - xml layout

Tags: android-xml

I'm just novice with android programming and designing with xml.

I have here this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PIMs.png. I want to create something similar to that, but I have no idea which layout I am going to use. I am also not sure about which widget I'm going to use.

I want to have something like the big image at top and populate some listview below it. I want the whole to be scrolled not just the listview is scrolling. Please help me with the xml coding for this.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/feauturedImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/featuredImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please add what the problem is? What is it doing now and what should it do?

Comment: @whereisSQL I want to achieve a similar look.

Comment: How is that image different from what your code is rendering right now? I am trying to hint that you might want to add some more details to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this helps you....

```
<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/featuredimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/bar" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list11"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/featuredimage"
    android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:listSelector="@color/itemcolor1">
    </ListView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```